# Async / Await with AngularFire2 toPromise() method wont work?

Tags: angular, async-await, angularfire2, angular2-observables

I just had a weird problem using AngularFire2 Observables, look at this code and tell me if you have a clue on what is happening :

```
async save(){
 const client = await this.getClient(this.id);
 console.log(client); // ZoneAwarePromise blah blah
}

getClient(clientId) {
 return this.db.object('clients/' + clientId)
            .valueChanges()
            .toPromise()
            .then((client: any) => {key: clientId, name: client.name});
}
```

So this code won't work, but if I do it like the next code, it will work :

```
async save(){
 const client = await this.getClient(this.id);
 console.log(client); // {key: 'blah', name: 'fooblah'}
}

getClient(clientId) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.db.object('clients/' + clientId)
            .valueChanges()
            .subscribe((client: any) => resolve({key: clientId, name: client.name}));
}
```

So how is it possible that creating a promise and resolve the Observable data works while the .toPromise() method won't work ?

Is it a normal behavior ? Am I doing something wrong ? Let me know :-)

Comment: hi i think your problem is the  .then((client: any) => {key: clientId, name: client.name}); line cause you're firing the promise

Comment: Hello @federicoscamuzzi thx for your answer but if I donc use the then() of the promise, my code just stops after 

`const client = await this.getClient(this.id);`

Even the console.log(client) won't fire :x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't work is because **your promise is never resolved**.

In order for your promise to be resolved, your *observable* needs to **`complete`**.

So if you simply prepend the toPromise() with ***`take(1)`***, you'll get the desired effect:

```
return this.db.object('clients/' + clientId)
              .valueChanges()
              .take(1)
              .toPromise();
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not test it but I believe it is the good answer. Thx mate :-)

Comment: alternatively, you can also use the **`first()`** operator instead of `take(1)`, which is more descriptive and better reflects the issue